# Custom dropdown menu not visible outside the modal when modal has scrollable content

Tags: jquery, css

- I have a custom dropdown inside a modal which is shown on the left side.
- My custom dropdown is triggered when the input is clicked
- As the modal has overflow scroll.The content goes below the modal, instead of popping out of modal.
- I have added a select2 example in the fiddle. I have added it on the right of the modal.Here the select2 dropdown shows the options popping out of the modal.

I have created a fiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/296v4Ld2/7/)

NOTE: I am developing a small plugin for my app that uses a custom dropdown as shown in the fiddle.So don't recommend third party plugins.

```js
$(function() {
  $('select').select2();
  $('#name').on('click', function() {
    $('.dropdown').show();
  });

  $('#name').on('blur', function() {
    $('.dropdown').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.modal-body {
  height: 250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 2000px;
}

.dropdown li {
  list-style: none;
}

.select2 {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <input type="text" id="name" />
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
            <li>c</li>
            <li>d</li>
            <li>e</li>
            <li>f</li>
            <li>g</li>
            <li>h</li>
            <li>i</li>
            <li>j</li>
            <li>k</li>
            <li>l</li>
            <li>m</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <select>
               <option>a</option>
               <option>b</option>
               <option>c</option>
               <option>d</option>
               <option>e</option>
               <option>f</option>
               <option>g</option>
               <option>h</option>
               <option>i</option>
               <option>j</option>
             </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question doesn't contain a question, nor a minimal, complete, verifiable example *in the question itself*. JSFiddle links are useful as a supplement, however the question should be able to stand entirely on its own without relying on external resources.

Comment: @Santi i have updated my question little better. I have added the fiddle because a working example would explain better.

Comment: Well done, I've removed my closure vote. That being said, StackOverflow has a Snippet button that allows you to embed runnable snippets into your question just like JSFiddle, and that satisfies the [MCVE Requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so your question doesn't risk closure. The button looks like this: `[<>]`. I will edit your question to run as a snippet - going forward it's a very useful tool to familiarize yourself with!